# Groovy - creating a valid XML file is not possible with single quote

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using XmlTemplateEngine to create several XML files. Currently I have a case where the XML generation fails. It fails if a single quote is used as a value of a xml tag.

Here is the method:

```
    public static void mergeXmlTemplateToFile(File src, File dest, Map bindings){
    File part = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath()+"/"+src.name)
    new XmlTemplateEngine().createTemplate(src).make(bindings).writeTo(new PrintWriter(part))
    XMLMerger merger = new XMLMerger(part, dest)
    merger.merge();
    part.delete()
}
```

call:

```
BuildUtils.mergeXmlTemplateToFile(new File(template+"area/cms/sharepoint.xml"), new File(output+"area/conf/config_complete.xml"), [servers:Builder.config.area.cms.sharepoint.servers, hostnames:Builder.config.server.hostnames])
```

The problem is, that the temporary file and the value of date.format has single quotes. The value of date.format need the single quotes. XmlTemplateEngine cannot use double quotes. I cannot use the temporary file for the next steps, because it's not valid. 
*[Fatal Error] sharepoint.xml: Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".*
Because this is not valid:

```
<property name='date.format' value='yyyy-MMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z''/>
```

Temporary file:

```
 <config>
  <cms>
    <type name='SharePoint'>
      <host ident=''>
        <property name='user' value='demo'/>
        <property name='password' value='pass'/>
        <property name='domain' value='example.com'/>
        <property name='date.format' value='yyyy-MMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z''/>
      </host>
    </type>
  </cms>
</config>
```

The template:

```
<config xmlns:gsp="http://groovy.codehaus.org/2005/gsp">
<cms>
    <ctype name="SharePoint">
        <gsp:scriptlet>servers.server.each { server -></gsp:scriptlet>
        <host ident="${server.ident.text()}">
            <property name="user" value="${server.user.text()}" />
            <property name="password" value="${server.password.text()}" />
            <property name="domain" value="${server.domain.text()}" />
            <property name="date.format" value="${server.dateformat.text()}" />
        </host>
        <gsp:scriptlet>}</gsp:scriptlet>
    </type>
</cms>
```

I have tried to use MarkupTemplateEngine instead of XmlTemplateEngine, but I had no success. http://www.groovy-lang.org/templating.html#_the_markuptemplateengine

```
TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();   
config.useDoubleQuotes = true;      
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config); 
engine.createTemplate(src).make(bindings).writeTo(new PrintWriter(part))




        import groovy.util.logging.Log4j;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import org.atteo.xmlcombiner.XmlCombiner
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
@Log4j
class XMLMerger {
    File src
    File dest

    public XMLMerger(File src, File dest){
        this.src = src
        this.dest = dest
    }


    public void merge(){
        merge(null)
    }

    public void merge(String id){
        if(src.exists() && dest.exists()){
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
            XmlCombiner combiner = new XmlCombiner();
            if(id != null)
                combiner = new XmlCombiner(id);
            combiner.combine(docBuilder.parse(dest))
            combiner.combine(docBuilder.parse(src))
            combiner.buildDocument(dest.toPath())
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs before the XMLMerger is called. 
Here is a example regarding the XmlTemplateEngine you can run online: http://goo.gl/A0pxfs

Thanks

Comment: What is `XmlMerger`?

Comment: I have posted the Xml Merger into my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a utility method in `XmlUtil` called `escapeXml`, so you can do:

```
import groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine
import static groovy.xml.XmlUtil.escapeXml

// Escape values going in to the binding
def binding = [dateformat: escapeXml("yyyy-MMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]

def engine = new XmlTemplateEngine()
def text = '''<config xmlns:gsp="http://groovy.codehaus.org/2005/gsp">
             |    <cms>
             |        <type name="SharePoint">
             |            <host ident="">
             |                <property name="user" value="" />
             |                <property name="password" value="" />
             |                <property name="domain" value="" />
             |                <property name="date.format" value="${dateformat}" />
             |            </host>
             |        </type>
             |    </cms>
             |</config>'''.stripMargin()

def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. You are the best! Thanks a lot for your help.